# awk to print the colums with condition on header

Tags: if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I have this kind of input:

```
Vel RMSE H D20120122 D20130404 X Y
0.5 0.1  3 4         5         2 2
```

I would like to print only the colums containing the string `D2`, in order to have as output the following:

```
D20120122 D20130404
4         5
```

I tried like this: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /D2/) printf $i}' myfile`

but it returns only the first row, i.e.:

`D20120122 D20130404`

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and  then [edit] your question to fix the formatting of your sample input, output, and code. By the way, it's probably not the cause of the problem you're asking about but never do `printf $i`, always do `printf "%s", $i` instead as the former will fail cryptically when your input contains printf formatting characters like `%s`.

Answer (score 3):

Using lengthy variable names for clarity:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    for ( inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++ ) {
        if ( $inFldNr ~ /D2/ ) {
            out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
        }
    }
}
{
    for ( outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++ ) {
        inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
D20120122 D20130404
4 5

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
D20120122  D20130404
4          5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option might be keeping track of the column numbers that match the pattern `D2` in the first row.

Then for the other rows, only print the matching field numbers.

```
awk '
BEGIN { ORS="" };
{
  if (NR==1) {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if($i ~ /D2/) {
        arr[++keyNr] = i
      }
    }
  }
  for (y=1; y<=keyNr; y++) {
    printf("%-10s", $arr[y])
  }
  print "\n"
}' myfile
```

Output

```
D20120122 D20130404 
4         5
```

[AWK demo](https://ideone.com/SjZFg2)

Comment: `for(y in a)` will shuffle the order of the fields, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Comment: @EdMorton I read a comment from you about a good read `GAWK: Effective AWK Programming`. I started reading into that, but I am not at that chapter yet :-) So the for loop sets the keys to 1,2 etc..and the reading from the array you specify the keys to read again in another for loop, am I right? Else the for..in construct uses hash keys and you don't know the order in which they are read?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It's simply that `for (i in a)` doesn't guarantee any particular order that the indices of `a[]` will be visited in so if you want an order you have to write the code to create that order. Some awk implementations will use hash order but it's completely implementation-dependent what any awk chooses to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'NR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i ~ /D2/) a[i] = 1}} NR > 1{for(i in a) print $i}' input
```

Comment: `for(i in a)` will shuffle the order of the fields, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Comment: also output is not in the format wanted by op.